# Proof of inequality involving logarithms

Tags: inequality, logarithms

How could we show that

$$\left|\log\left( \left({1 + \frac{1}{n}}\right)^{n + \frac{1}{2}}\cdot \frac{1}{e}\right)\right| \leq \left|\log\left( \left({1 - \frac{1}{n}}\right)^{n - \frac{1}{2}}\cdot \frac{1}{e}\right)\right| ,\; \forall n \text{ sufficiently large?} $$

I already calculated in wolfram the limit of the quotient of the logs when $n \rightarrow \infty$. And it is zero. However, I can't prove it.

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: I edited your latex to make it appear as what I think it should. (moved brackets and backslashes around) Can you double check that the inequality is correctly stated?

Comment: @julien, you can't multiply by $e$, because the logarithm turns products into sums, which may in turn yield sign changes, and because absolute values are taken, you can't just remove them on both sides.

Comment: @Lieven Sure. Either I was blind, or these parentheses have changed in between. Checked. Yeah, they've been changed...

Comment: Yeah, they've changed, I was having some troubles with Latex. Fixed it now.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean $\cdot e$ instead of $\cdot\frac1e$ on the right hand side?

Comment: Do you accept a proof using limits or do you want to prove the inequality without applying them?

Comment: You can use limits

Comment: @ExampleMo. I've undeleted my answer based on the use of limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to prove that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\log \left( \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right) ^{n+1/2}
\frac{1}{e}\right) =0$$
and
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\log \left( \left( 1-\frac{1}{n}\right) ^{n-1/2}\frac{1}{e}\right) =-2.$$

The first limit can be evaluated as follows:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\log \left( \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right) ^{n+1/2}\frac{1}{e}\right)  &=&\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right) -1 \\
&=&\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }n\log \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\log \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right) -1 \\
&=&\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\log \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right) }{\frac{1}{n}}+0-1 \\
&=&1-1=0;
\end{eqnarray*}$$

and the second:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\log \left( \left( 1-\frac{1}{n}\right) ^{n-1/2}\frac{1}{e}\right)  &=&\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\log \left( 1-\frac{1}{n}\right) -1 \\
&=&\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }n\log \left( 1-\frac{1}{n}\right) -\frac{1}{2}%
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\log \left( 1-\frac{1}{n}\right) -1 \\
&=&\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\log \left( 1-\frac{1}{n}\right) }{\frac{1}{n}}-0-1 \\
&=&-1-1=-2.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

The left hand side is
$$
\begin{align}
&\left|\,\left(n+\frac12\right)\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)-1\,\right|\\
&=\left(n+\frac12\right)\left(\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{3n^3}-\frac1{4n^4}+\dots\right)-1\\
&=\frac1{3\cdot4n^2}-\frac2{4\cdot6n^3}+\frac3{5\cdot8n^4}-\frac4{6\cdot10n^5}+\dots+\frac{(-1)^k(k-1)}{2k(k+1)n^k}+\dots\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
The right hand side is
$$
\begin{align}
&\left|\,\left(n-\frac12\right)\log\left(1-\frac1n\right)-1\,\right|\\
&=\left(n-\frac12\right)\left(\frac1n+\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{3n^3}+\frac1{4n^4}+\dots\right)+1\\
&=2+\frac1{3\cdot4n^2}+\frac2{4\cdot6n^3}+\frac3{5\cdot8n^4}+\frac4{6\cdot10n^5}+\dots+\frac{(k-1)}{2k(k+1)n^k}+\dots\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the left hand side tends to $0$ and the right hand side tends to $2$.

---

However, assuming that the inequality is actually
$$
\left|\,\log\left(\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+\frac12}\cdot\frac1e\right)\,\right| \le\left|\,\log\left(\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n-\frac12}\cdot e\right)\,\right|\tag{3}
$$
The right hand side is
$$
\begin{align}
&\left|\,\left(n-\frac12\right)\log\left(1-\frac1n\right)+1\,\right|\\
&=\left(n-\frac12\right)\left(\frac1n+\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{3n^3}+\frac1{4n^4}+\dots\right)-1\\
&=\frac1{3\cdot4n^2}+\frac2{4\cdot6n^3}+\frac3{5\cdot8n^4}+\frac4{6\cdot10n^5}+\dots+\frac{(k-1)}{2k(k+1)n^k}+\dots\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the left hand side is still smaller than the right hand side, but the difference is much smaller.